# How to call a function cross files JavaScript VisualStudioCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

so I a function in 1 file that returns the result of 2 numbers.

However in my other file I need to invoke this function to save it's value in a local variable i create, then I will print the variables value to the console.

I know how to print, but I'm stuck at calling this function from another file.
I have no idea of how to do this, and when I google I only find how to do it in a HTML file and it seems to differ.

Can anyone help me?

TL;DR I need to call a function from another file that returns 2 numbers. THen save them in a variable locally in the file that calls it from the other.

Comment: What are you writing it for/in, an extension, a nodeJS app?

Comment: You probably need to write the first function as part of a module, then import it in the main file.

Comment: I am not sure if it has anything to do with VSCode. Answer may differ based on if you are writing it for browser (ES5 or ES6), NodeJS, or else.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: VS Code is an editor. You said "I only find how to do it in a HTML file" which implies you are not running your JS via `<script>` elements in a webpage. Telling us what you don't want to do only goes so far. Tell us what you do want to do. (I suppose you might be writing a VS Code extension, but you should explicitly say so if you are.). You should provide a [mcve] too.